# if condition containing ++y vs y+=1

Tags: c

Here is the following code :

```
int main () {
   int x = 3, y = 0 ;
   if(x >= 3 && y+=1){
     if(y<=5){
       printf("%d\n", ++x);
     } 
   }
   else{
     printf("%d\n", x++);
   }
   printf("x=%d, y=%d", x, y++);
   return 0;
}
```

It is not working, and `y+=1` is the cause of it, I thought it would act the same way as if i would replace it with `++y` (which works).

Why if i replace y+=1 with ++y the code works?
why y+=1 causes the code to fail ?

Comment: Pro-tip: Don't combine increment operators within expressions. You're not saving any cpu cycles and all you've done is made your code less readable and less maintainable.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? What is supposed to happen? What actually happens? What is the expected and actual output? Please [edit] your question to tell us.

Comment: @selbie would never do it, it is a test question...

Comment: You still haven't explained what's "not working". What is the expected result, and what is happening instead?

Comment: Your code does not compile. Change `(x >= 3 && y += 1)` to `(x >= 3 && (y += 1))`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: When you're getting a compiler error, include the exact error in the question

Comment: _"Not working"_ is not a problem description. You should have told us that the program does not compile and you should have shown the error message. Read this before posting your next question:  [ask]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x >= 3 && y+=1` is equivalent to `(x >= 3 && y)+=1` while `x >= 3 && ++y` is equivalent to `(x >= 3) && (++y)`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is operator precedence. `+=` has lower precedence than `&&`, so

```
if (x >= 3 && y += 1)
```

is parsed as

```
if (((x >= 3) && y) += 1)
```

This isn't valid because `((x >= 3) && y)` is not an lvalue that can be incremented.

Add parentheses to override this.

```
if (x >= 3 && (y+=1)){
```